# How to intercept when the action start and store is updated?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I am using NGRX. I have many actions and I want to know when actions start and when the store is updated.

The idea is to have a centralized way to get the information no matter what action is executed. I need to know when the store updates without subscribing to all selectors.

updateTitle ----> title is updated.

best,
Hmendez

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly define actions

e.g.

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";    

export enum HeaderActionTypes {
  UpdateTitle = '[Title] Update Title',
  UpdateTitleSuccess = '[Title] Update Title success'
}

export const UpdateTitle = createAction(HeaderActionTypes.UpdateTitle)
export const UpdateTitleSuccess = createAction(HeaderActionTypes.UpdateTitleSuccess, props<{ payload: string }>())
```

in reducer you can catch actions and update the state

e.g

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";

export const initialState = {
   ... // Additional state properties can go here. 
   updatingTitle: false,
   title: ''
}


export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(HeaderActionTypes.UpdateTitle, (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      updatingTitle: true
   }
  }),
  on(HeaderActionTypes.UpdateTitleSuccess, (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      updatingTitle: false,
      title: payload
   }
  })
)
```

If `title` is getting updated with `async` call you have to add an `Effect`

[Effect](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects), Checkout the documentation.

[Selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors), Use selectors to read state and bind it to UI.